# Where can I find the APN settings for an unlocked AT&T iPhone 4 running iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

Today I unlocked my AT&T iPhone 4 running iOS 7 (the official method via AT&T).  In order to use my phone abroad next month I'm told I'll need to be able to set APN settings but I can't find them anywhere on my device.

I believe the unlock was successful as iTunes showed a confirmation message saying so.

I've tried looking in various places suggested by posts on various message boards but I can't find the settings anywhere.

Comment: try this http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1642124&highlight=apn+settings

Comment: and this http://community.48months.ie/t5/Most-Popular-Questions/iOS-7-Internet-and-MMS-set-up/td-p/8493

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: @MK I'm running 10.8.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still have the AT&T -SIM card (To verify, go into Settings > General > About > Carrier), AT&T will not allow you to change the APN settings, even on unlocked phone.

You need a SIM card from a carrier that [allows APN settings change](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1642124), that will depend on where are you going. Usually if you go to the new carrier they have a section [explaining](http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-2383) how to.

Some more helpful [information](http://community.48months.ie/t5/Most-Popular-Questions/iOS-7-Internet-and-MMS-set-up/td-p/8493).

Answer (score 2):

You need to Reset your Network settings and make sure you don't have any profile saved by you, and after resetting it go to the cellular network menu and you will see the APN settings.

Comment: works for me :-)... i didn't get back the APN setting but the 3G was auto enabled and i guess auto cfg by my local carrier... (after reset network setting and with AT&T official unlock the IPhone.)

Answer (score 1):

You will not find the APN settings in iOS 7. I spent forever on this and finally just downloaded the profile for my carrier using:

http://www.unlockit.co.nz/unlockit/

Follow the directions on the right side of the screen. Do it with a wireless connection from your iPhone and know your specific carrier. Worked like a charm for me as I can now access the internet using my data plan. No reason to pay for unlocking or jailbreaking.

Comment: make sure to open it from your iphone using the safari browser. If you open it from chrome it will say "download failed" after you click "create apn"

Answer (score 1):

Usually iOS devices don’t need a manual setup to connect to AT&T cellular internet services if you purchased a compatible data plan and sim.
However, in case your iOS device is unable to connect to AT&T cellular internet service, follow the steps given in [AT&T APN setting guide](https://www.onlineprivacytips.co/guides/setup-att-apn-settings/) to resolve the issue.

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link, the idea is to have the answer stand on its own in case the linked page disappear. Can you please summarize the relevant part directly into your answer and leave the link for reference?

Answer (score 0):

if APN changing is enabled by your service provider, you should be able to change the APN using the instructions given here: http://apn.gishan.net/platform_14_iphone_5s_.php

Go to above link and choose your network. If your network is outside US use this site: http://apnsettings.gishan.net/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the symptom was the same after we returned from Germany and put the original AT&T SIM back in. The issue was that while in Germany, we used a service from Aldi (was very good) that as part of its set-up installed a profile on the phone. It is this profile that caused the issue when returning to the U.S. Here is what I did to fix it:

1. Go to Settings → General
2. Scroll down to Profiles and then tap on it.
3. Remove the offending profile (do not remove all profiles)